# Add Guid.NewGuid into SQL database problem

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with adding new record into Users table in my database. I have ID as uniqueidentifier and I try to add new record from C# using Guid.NewGuid() as this ID.

SQL returns error, that ID cannot be null. I was trying add record with this generated Guid ID in database and I see the same error, but if i will add record using sql NewId I see that record succesfully added.

I have database created using Code First from EF. Project is created in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Anyone can help me with this?

SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

C# Code:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, Guid> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>
{ }

public class MyRole : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole>
{
}

public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
}

public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
{ }

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<User, MyRole, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<MyRole, Guid, UserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class RecruitmentDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, MyRole, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public RecruitmentDbContext()
        : base("RecruitmentDB")
    {
    }

    public static RecruitmentDbContext Create()
    {
        return new RecruitmentDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(prop => prop.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Ignore(col => col.PhoneNumber)
            .Ignore(col => col.EmailConfirmed)
            .Ignore(col => col.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
            .Ignore(col => col.TwoFactorEnabled)
            .Ignore(col => col.LockoutEnabled)
            .Ignore(col => col.AccessFailedCount);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .ToTable("Users");

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyRole>()
            .ToTable("Roles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .ToTable("UserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>()
            .ToTable("UserClaims");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>()
            .ToTable("UserLogins");
    }
}
```

And my Register Action in the C# Controller where the error is throwing

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    try
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                await _userManager.FindAsync(user.UserName, user.PasswordHash);
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

But as I said before, generated GUID copied from C# to Insert Table Query in the SQL throws the same error.

Manager:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<User, Guid> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<RecruitmentDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, Guid>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        //manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        //{
        //    MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //});
        //manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        //{
        //    Subject = "Security Code",
        //    BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //});
        //manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        //manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        //var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        //if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        //{
        //    manager.UserTokenProvider = 
        //        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        //}
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't help without code, but a GUID as a primary key is a bad idea unless they are specifically sequential because it is very inefficient for the database engine.

Comment: You really should post a minimal sample of your code to illustrate what you've done. It could be that you have not told EF that the property in question is the PK, or perhaps you have told it that it should be automatically generated by the database but you're overriding that, etc, etc. Posting your code will help us to help you figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line from the mapper:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(prop => prop.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Also, remove this from User class:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

because you are setting it into your code and it is not the responsibility of the database as per your table creation SQL query.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see your edit, but it helps. Of course i removed this atribute also.